# Code injection technique with Selenium for file uploads stopped working with Chrome 117

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I use Selenium and C# to test a large, hosted application. The test environment is Chrome and Windows 10/11. File uploads on the live site are via Windows dialogs. I bypass those dialogs using  code injection onto the HTMLInputElement associated with a context menu item (see the code below) followed by a SendKeys(path-to-the-files) call on that element. This has worked well for years. It would seem a recent update to Chrome 117 and associated Selenium libraries has broken this technique.

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver.WebDriver).ExecuteScript(
    "HTMLInputElement.prototype.click = function() {" +
    "   if(this.type !== 'file') HTMLElement.prototype.click.call(this);" +
    "};"
);
```

The dev console now shows an 'Uncaught Error: Argument to isShown must be of type Element ... ' with references to executeScript.

Suggestions?

Comment: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/12780    -  Similar issue reported to the Selenium team.

Comment: The update to selenium 4.13.1 fixed the issue.